# Vacant thumbnail spot persists on Chrome homepage, want to set it specific to a site

Tags: google-chrome, thumbnails, homepage

I have a vacant thumbnail place in Google Chrome that I would like to set for a particular site. In this case, it's Facebook.

When I visit a new website a new thumbnail is created for that site in the sixth spot.

Wanting to place Facebook at the sixth location I deleted the new thumbnail and visited Facebook again.

But the sixth place remains vacant no matter how often I visit Facebook.

What can I do to set a specific thumbnail position a particular site?

Comment: @random Wow! Thanks for your kind editing. Is there a way to view the original text so I can learn what's wrong in the first place? I'll be very helpful to my English learning.

Comment: Click the link that says "edited [timeframe]" to see the list of versions and what changed between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably deleted it once, chrome remembers this, theres a little link at the top right of the thumbnails that says "Restore all removed thumbnails" hit it.